# Is it possible to display gridview or table instead of listbox which appears when autocomplete is enabled?

Tags: windows, autocomplete

I want to develop YUI auto-complete like auto-complete in my program in c#.net (VS2005). It a windows application. Is it possible to show search result in gridview or table when characters are entered in textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Doing exactly what you requested is very easy. Just add the `TextChanged` event to your text box and do a search anytime it is changed.

```
private void textHost_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Do search and update the results
}
```

However, you have to consider that if your search to get results takes more then a trivial amount of time, the user will be annoyed when their is a lag with each character typed. For this you should use `BackgroundWorker` and do the search in a background thread. When a new key is pressed call the `Cancel` method on the thread and kick off a new one.

If you want to get even more complicated you can set up a background thread that is signalled each time a key is pressed. If no new signal is received for a half second or so, you start the background search.